# Suppose $Y\subset X$ then find an example that the order topology on $Y$ is not the relativized order topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for an example showing that the relativization of the order topology to $Y$ is not the same as the order topology on $X$. I figured I would begin by trying to find subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ since the order topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the usual topology. However, I am having trouble determining the relativization of the order topology to $Y$. This seems very intuitive to me but I would like a concrete example. I figured something like $Y=(0,1)\cup\{2\}$ should do the trick but what exactly is the relativization of the order topology to $Y$ in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that basic open sets in the order topology on an ordered set $X$ are intervals of the form $(a, b)$, $(-\infty, a)$ or $(b, \infty)$ *where $a$ and $b$ are in the space $X$*.

In $\mathbb{R}$'s order topology $(1.5, 2.5)$ is an open set, and therefore $(1.5, 2.5) \cap Y$ is open in the relative topology on $Y$; you can see that $\{2\} = (1.5, 2.5) \cap Y$, so $\{2\}$ is open in the relative topology.

On the other hand, in the order topology on $Y$, $\{2\}$ does not contain any interval of the form $(a, \infty)$ or $(a, b)$ with $a$ and $b$ in $Y$ itself.  Thus $\{2\}$ is not open in the order topology of $Y$, as it contains no basic open set.

Answer (score 1):

That is a case where the order topology does not coincide with the topology as subspace, yes, but the topology is not completely straightforward: any open set containing the point $2$ has some point of $(0,1)$. The picture you should have in your mind is subsets of the form $\{2\}\cup(1-\frac{1}{n},1)$.

The subset $\{-\pi-\sqrt{2}-10^6\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is easier to understand, or any of this kind.